# Catch except in __enter__()

Tags: python, class, oop, contextmanager

I wanted to try using the context manager mode. They say he's better. It can also catch exceptions and is better readable.

```
with my_class() as some:
    some.do()
```

The examples I found all look like this:

```
class Exm:
    def __init__(self):
        some_data_get
        connection = connection_to_resource_good   # for example 1

    def __enter__(self):
        connection = connection_to_resource_good    # for example 2
        return connection

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        connection.close()
        return some_True    # for continue code if some error in some.do()
```

But in the examples I've seen, no one catches an exception when accessing a resource. If there is an error in the connection, then this will break the continuation of the code

```
class My:
    def __init__(self):
        print("INIT")

    def __enter__(self):
        connection = 1 / 0      # error bad connection
        return connection

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb): # not call - error in init or enter
        connection.close()
        return some_True    # for continue code if some error in some.do()
```

Here is a more specific example:

```
class DB:

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, db_name):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db_name = db_name

    def __enter__(self):
        self.connection = name_some_module_for_sql.connection(self.host, self.user, self.password, self.db_name)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        return self.cursor

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.cursor.close()
        self.connection.close()
        return True  # for continue code
```

for an example in the code, you need to insert in three places

```
with DB(1, 1, 1, 1) as cursor:  # into db_1
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Hello")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("My")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Dear")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Friend")

with DB(2, 2, 2, 2) as cursor:  # into db_2
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Hello")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("My")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Dear")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Friend")

with DB(3, 3, 3, 3) as cursor:  # into db_3
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Hello")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("My")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Dear")
    cursor.insert_to_db_word("Friend")
```

How can I handle exceptions in the init or enter functions so that the cursor.insert_to_db_word functions are not called and the program code continues to be executed if there is a problem connecting to the first database?

Only for class

P.S. sorry for google translete

Before that, I implemented it with decorators. I wanted to use a class for beautiful code and readability

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to transparently skip the entire `with` block from within `__enter__`, if that's what you're after.

An exception raised in `__enter__` will be propagated as usual, so assuming `__enter__` raises `DBError`, you can do

```
try:
    with DB(...) as db:
        db.foo()
except DBError:
    pass
```

You can also handle the error within `__enter__` (hopefully logging it!), and return something other than a valid connection, e.g. None, and check for that within your block:

```
with DB(...) as db:
    if db:
        db.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

`__exit__` is not there for "suppressing" the exceptions. Its main idea is to ensure that there is a piece of code which always gonna be executed even if an exception occurs "*inside*" that block of code. Since an exception might occur it gives the ability to inspect that object and possibly suppress it by returning `True` in some situations.

With that being said I think it doesn't make sense for `__enter__` to also have this ability to suppress exceptions. You need `try-except` block for that inside `__enter__`(like anywhere else in the code).